# Qual a diferença entre break, pass e continue em Python?

Tags: python, controle-de-fluxo, característica-linguagem

A documentação do Python em português é um trabalho em andamento, e razoavelmente confusa [como podem ver](http://www.python.org.br/wiki/PythonDoc).

Tenho dificuldades em inglês e achei [esse](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) site que não consigo ler.

Portanto, como posso usar `break`, `pass` e `continue` para controlar fluxos de programas em Python?

Tem exemplos?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Se traduzirmos as palavras, elas nos dão uma dica do que elas realmente fazem com o fluxo:

- `break`: é quebrar, quebra (ou interrompe) o fluxo natural do programa
- `continue`: é continuar, ou seja, continua o fluxo natural do ciclo
- `pass`: é passar, ou seja, deixa passar.

Essas coisas ficam mais claras com um exemplo:

```py
numeros = list()
for i in xrange(10):
    numeros.append(i)
```

Ao imprimirmos a lista, obtemos:

```py
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Vamos então testar nossos comandos de controle de fluxo:

### Break

```py
for item in numeros:
    if item >= 2:
        break
    print item
```

O `break` deverá quebrar a execução do `for`, e é exatamente o que acontece, obtemos o seguinte resultado:

```py
0
1
```

### Continue

Agora para o `continue`:

```py
for item in numeros:
    if item == 4:
        continue
    print item
```

O `continue` deverá continuar a execução do `for`, que quando encontrar um item igual a quatro, passará para a próxima iteração. E recebemos o resultado sem o `4`:

```py
0
1
2
3
5
6
7
8
9
```

Como apontado por @MarcoAurelio, não faz sentido colocarmos um continue no final da lista de comandos de um ciclo, já que não há mais nada a fazer e o ciclo automaticamente passará à próxima iteração.

### Pass

O `pass` é uma palavra que deve ser usada sempre que o programa requisitar sintaticamente que se preencha uma lacuna, como é o caso da definição de uma função: após a linha do `def` tem que haver algum conteúdo.

```py
def soma_de_quadrados(x, y):
    pass # k = x**x + y**y
    # return k
```

O código acima garante que, ainda que eu não esteja certo a respeito da função, ela possa existir e ser usada no resto do meu código, sem apresentar erros.

Comment: `pass` é o que alguns processadores chamam de `NOOP` =)