# Qual é a importância de indentar o código?

Tags: indentação

É comum ouvir que é importante manter o código indentado, o que não é uma tarefa difícil com ajuda de uma IDE.

Excluindo as linguagens que obrigam a indentação, como Python, por que é importante manter o código indentado? Seria somente a mérito de legibilidade?

Além do programador, quem lê o código é o compilador. Faz alguma diferença para ele, nas linguagens que não obrigam a indentação, processar o código com uma boa/má/sem identação?

Comment: 22h da noite , você cansado , virada de implantação ou algo assim ,  ai precisa analisar um código de uma linguagem que não domina muito em um módulo do sistema que tem um conhecimento parco , não precisa alterar só mesmo tirar uma dúvida , aí você pega um código bagunçado e não indentado ...

Comment: Uma observação: a indentação no Python é obrigatória, sim.

Comment: Tá, mas é indentação ou identação? :)

Comment: @MurilloGoulart, o correto é [indentação](https://duvidas.dicio.com.br/identacao-ou-indentacao/). Identar não existe na língua portuguesa.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss bom comentário, um adicional: temos uma comunidade sobre português na rede e tem esta pergunta inclusive sobre o assunto [**Identar, indentar, ou endentar?**](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/1823/8)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Serve para manter o código mais fácil de entender.

Por exemplo, veja este código sem indentação alguma:

```
if (a) {
if (b) {
while (c) {
d();
}
} else if (e) {
f();
} else if (g) {
h();
}
} else if (i) {
while (j) {
k();
}
}
```

Agora veja o mesmo código com uma indentação muito mal-feita:

```
if (a) {
    if (b)
  {
        while (c) {
    d();
}
  }
else
      if (e)
 {
 f();
        }
else if (g)
       {
      h();
              }
   } else
 if (i) {
    while (j) {
      k();
         }
    }
```

E agora o código bem indentado:

```
if (a) {
    if (b) {
        while (c) {
            d();
        }
    } else if (e) {
        f();
    } else if (g) {
        h();
    }
} else if (i) {
    while (j) {
        k();
    }
}
```

Observe que no código bem indentado, é muito mais fácil se perceber logo de cara, como é que as estruturas estão aninhadas. Já no código sem indentação, o que o olho e o cérebro humano vê é apenas uma sopa de abre e fecha chaves, `if`s, `while`s, etc e fica difícil saber onde as coisas começam e onde terminam. No código mal-indentado, é ainda pior, pois há um esforço mental extra em perceber que a indentação sugerida é inadequada e entender qual seria a correta.

Enfim, tudo se resume a facilitar a leitura do código para um humano, e não para uma máquina.

Em especial, veja esses exemplos terríveis onde a indentação errada faz as instruções parecerem estar no lugar errado:

```
if (x)
    y();
    z();
```

```
if (a)
    if (b)
        c();
else
    d();
```

```
if (x)
    // y();

z();
```

No primeiro caso, o `z()` parece estar dentro do `if`, mas está fora. No segundo caso, o `else` está no `if` interno, mas foi indentado como se estivesse no externo. No terceiro caso, como a linha do `y()` foi comentada, o `z()` acabou entrando de carona dentro do `if`. Esses casos patológicos são evitados se você delimitar o escopo sempre com chaves (ou o equivalente dependendo da linguagem) ou usar uma linguagem sensível a indentação como o Python.

Para o compilador, a indentação quase sempre não importa. A principal exceção é obviamente o Python, onde o compilador se utiliza da indentação para aninhar as estruturas. Uma outra exceção que lembro é de Scheme/Racket, onde embora o compilador não precise da indentação quando o código está correto, no caso de haver um erro de compilação ele vai usar a indentação para sugerir onde é o local mais provável do erro ter ocorrido.

Answer (score 4):

> A [resposta do @Victor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/190456/64969) trata perfeitamente de linguagens *curly bracketed*, as demais focam em questões mais conceituais

Em Python, código mal identado não é nem código válido:

```
# inválido
if marmota:
marmotante()
executoso()

# válido 
if suricate:
    seboso()
executoso()
```

Também perceba que a identação define os blocos. Então, caso se dê `suricate`, então executamos `seboso`, caso não se dê, não executamos `seboso`; já `executoso` sempre é executado, independente do retorno de `suricate`.

A questão de identação e blocos de códigos em Python é tão forte que *statements* que necessitam um bloco de código em seguida, precisam ter pelo menos uma operação de `noop` identada (vide essa pergunta: [Qual a diferença entre break, pass e continue em python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/322/64969) )

```
# exemplo copiado da resposta da pergunta acima
def soma_de_quadrados(x, y):
    pass # noop, nenhuma operação =]
```

Não conheço nenhuma outra linguagem que preza por identação forte como o Python preza, normalmente a identação é algo que o autor faz para o leitor do código, estando preso a elementos sintáticos.

Answer (score 3):

A identação é um recurso fundamental para a legibilidade de um código, pois adiciona informação importante, do tipo: qual bloco de código pertence a uma função ou método? Ela também ajuda a entender a hierarquia de elementos em código HTML e XML. Acredito que todo programador já espera encontrar algum tipo de indentação quando vai ler qualquer código.

A indentação é completamente irrelevante para o compilador, já que ele elimina quaisquer caracteres não significativos para a sua análise.

Mas lembre-se:

> Qualquer idiota pode escrever código que um computador entenda. Bons
>   programadores escrevem código que humanos podem entender. - Martin
>   Fowler

Mais sobre o tema pode ser encontrado [aqui](https://www.reddit.com/r/stackunderflow/comments/5yng9a/indenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o_tabs_ou_espa%C3%A7os/).

Answer (score 1):

A indentação é bastante importante.
Para pessoas que seguem profissões de programação há que ter em conta que não estamos a trabalhar sozinhos e que outras pessoas poderão ter de via a pegar no nosso trabalho. Quem diz a indentação diz o uso de comentários.

Algumas empresas grandes como a Google/Microsoft têm até regras de organização de código para diferentes projetos. Estas regras incluem indentação/comentários/organização do código em geral etc.