# Como criar vetores que armazenem as vogais do alfabeto?

Tags: c

Preciso resolver um exercício proposto em que as vogais sejam armazenadas pro vetores. Sou iniciante, e não entendi pq a tela de execução não mostra os valores. Utilizando apenas C por enquanto.

```
int main (int argc, char**argv){

char vogal[TAM];
int cont;

vogal[0] = 'a';
vogal[1] = 'e';
vogal[2] = 'i';
vogal[3] = 'o';
vogal[4] = 'u';


/*Lendo */
printf("\n\n\t Mostrando os valores dos vetores \n");
printf("\n Posição 0: %s",vogal[0]);
printf("\n Posição 1: %s",vogal[1]);
printf("\n Posição 2: %s",vogal[2]);
printf("\n Posição 2: %s",vogal[3]);
printf("\n Posição 2: %s",vogal[4]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Observação 1:**

> A primeira coisa que tem que ser observada no código da pergunta é a falta de
> indentação.
> Veja aqui [Qual é a importância de indentar o código?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190450/137387):
>
> *A identação é um recurso fundamental para a legibilidade de um código, pois adiciona informação importante, do tipo: qual bloco de
> código pertence a uma função ou método*




**Observação 2:**

> O identificador `TAM` não foi declarado por conveniência vou declarar como > uma macro:
>
> ```
> #define TAM 5
> ```
>
> Veja em [Quando usar const e quando usar #define?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136467/137387):
> *Esse tipo de declaração é apenas um texto sendo substituído por outro sem nenhum tipo de verificação. Em geral deve ser evitado sempre que
> possível. Mas há casos úteis.*




**Observação 3:**

> A variável não inicializada `int cont;` foi declara e não é utilizada
> em porção alguma do exemplo da pergunta. Então sua menção foi
> suprimida dessa resposta.

### Solução:

São dois os problemas com o seu código:

1. A declaração do array `char vogal[TAM];` não foi devidamente inicializado. Faltou reservar espaço para o terminador de string `\0`.
2. O especificador formato especificado para imprimir nas linhas `printf("\n Posição 0: %s",vogal[n]);`, onde `n` é um número no intervalo `[0,5[`, não é adequado para o tipo do argumento.

Também pode ser melhorada a impressão, ao invés de imprimir um caractere por linha pode ser usado um laço de iteração `for` para simplificar a tarefa.

Uma solução rápida seria inicializar explicitamente o array vogal e iterar por seus caracteres, os imprimindo com o especificador de formato `%c` , até encontrar um terminador de string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAM 5                                             //define a macro TAM como 5.

int main (int argc, char**argv){

  char vogal[TAM + 1] = "aeiou";                          //declara o array vogal e o inicia explicitamente alocando um espaço extra para o terminador \0.
    
  printf("\n\n\t Mostrando os valores dos vetores \n");
  for(int i = 0; vogal[i] != '\0'; i++){                  //Para i incrementando enquanto vogal[i] não for o terminador de string...
    printf("\n Posição %d: %c", i, vogal[i]);             //...imprime posição e a vogal.
  }
}
```

Essa solução a baixo também é simples mas pode mascarar um erro com a  inicialização da strings, pois a solução funciona mesmo que a string tenha sido declarada sem o terminador de strings...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAM 5

int main (int argc, char**argv){

  char vogal[TAM + 1] = "aeiou";  
    
  printf("\n\n\t Mostrando os valores dos vetores \n");
  for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++){                         //Para i incrementando de 0 a TAM....
    printf("\n Posição %d: %c", i, vogal[i]);           //...imprime posição e a vogal.
  }
}
```

...veja o exemplo abaixo que força uma declaração equivocada de string simulando o esquecimento do terminador `\0`.

```
/******************************************************************/
/*  AVISO: Esse fragmento possui um erro propositalmente embutido */
/******************************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAM 5

int main (int argc, char**argv){

  char vogal[TAM] = "aeiou";                            //Aqui a string foi declarada sem o espaço destinado ao terminador de strings.
    
  printf("\n\n\t Mostrando os valores dos vetores \n");
  for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++){                         //Esse trecho de código irá funcionar normalmente.
    printf("\n Posição %d: %c", i, vogal[i]);
  }

  printf("Texto: %s", vogal);                           //Aqui será gerado um erro de impressão.
}

/* Resultado do código a cima
     Mostrando os valores dos vetores 

 Posição 0: a
 Posição 1: e
 Posição 2: i
 Posição 3: o
 Posição 4: uTexto: aeiouHE�9 <--Aqui o erro de impressão gerado pela ausência do terminador de string.
*/
```

Mas o por que dessas soluções?

### Como inicializar arrays de caracteres.

Uma coisa que deve ser dita é que em C não existe o tipo string, C só trabalha com um array de caracteres o array não inclui o seu tamanho, única forma de identificar o fim de string em C é usar o terminador `\0`. Então quando declarar um array lembre-se de adicionar espaço para o terminador. Mais informações [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/327107/137387)

São duas formas de inicializar o array. Uma forma de inicialização é implícita e a outra forma de inicialização explicita.

**Inicialização implícita de arrays:**
Inicialização implica é aquela onde a variável é declarada mas nenhum valor inicial é atribuído, é o mesmo tipo de inicialização que usou na pergunta.

```
//Inicialização de valores implícitos do array vogal[].
char vogal[TAM];       //Não é possível afirmar que todos os compiladores irão iniciar com string vazia {`\0`, `\0`, `\0`, `\0`, `\0`, `\0`}
```

Na maioria das linguagens nesse tipo de inicialização as variáveis recebem um valor na falta(zero, string vazia), mas em C [esse tipo de inicialização deve ser evitado](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/uninitialized-variables-and-undefined-behavior/) pois não é definido um comportamento padronizado então em alguns compiladores sim terá uma string vazia noutros poderá receber uma string contendo resíduo de memória.

**Inicialização explicita de arrays:**
Ao inicializar um objeto do tipo [array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/527512/137387), o inicializador pode ser uma string literal ou ser uma lista de elementos delimitada por chaves.

```
//Inicializando o array vogal[] com uma string literal... 
char vogal[TAM + 1] = "aeiou";                   //{'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', '\0'}

//Inicializando o array vogal[] com uma lista de caracteres... 
char vogal[TAM + 1] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}; //{'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', '\0'}
```

A partir do C versão 99 também é possível inicializar um array com uma lista contendo designadores de indices junto aos elementos:

```
//Inicializando o array vogal[] com uma lista de caracteres usando designadores de índices...
char vogal[TAM + 1] = { [4]='u', [2]='i', [0]='a', [3]='o', [1]='e'}; //{'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', '\0'}
//Na falta de designadores a inicialização continua em ordem, começando com o próximo elemento após o descrito pelo designador.
char vogal[TAM + 1] = { [4]='u', [0]='a', 'e', 'i', 'o'};             //{'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', '\0'}
```

Também é possível inicializar um array com uma string vazia para posterior modificação:

```
//Inicializando o array vogal[5] com uma string vazia...
char vogal[TAM+1] = "";       //{`\0`, `\0`, `\0`, `\0`, `\0`, `\0`}

vogal[0] = 'a';
vogal[1] = 'e';
vogal[2] = 'i';
vogal[3] = 'o';
vogal[4] = 'u';
```

### Imprimindo arrays e caracteres.

A função [`int printf( const char * formato, ... );`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) imprime os dados formatados para fluxo de saída [`stdout`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/std_streams). `printf()` grava a string apontada pelo parâmetro `formato` na saída padrão, se `formato` incluir especificadores de formato(substrings que começam com %), os argumentos adicionais após `formato` são formatados e inseridos na string resultante substituindo seus respectivos especificadores.

Tabela de formatadores de printf:

| especificador | Saída | Exemplo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| d ou i | Número inteiro decimal assinado | 392 |
| u | Número inteiro decimal sem sinal | 7235 |
| o | Octal não assinado | 610 |
| x | Inteiro hexadecimal não assinado | 7fa |
| X | Inteiro hexadecimal não assinado (maiúsculas) | 7FA |
| f | Ponto flutuante decimal, minúsculo | 392,65 |
| F | Ponto flutuante decimal, maiúsculo | 392,65 |
| e | Notação científica (mantissa/expoente), minúscula | 3,9265e+2 |
| E | Notação científica (mantissa/expoente), maiúscula | 3,9265E+2 |
| g | Use a representação mais curta: %e ou %f | 392,65 |
| G | Use a representação mais curta: %E ou %F | 392,65 |
| a | Ponto flutuante hexadecimal, minúsculo | -0xc.90fep-2 |
| A | Ponto flutuante hexadecimal, maiúscula | -0XC.90FEP-2 |
| **c** | **Caractere** | a |
| **s** | **Cadeia de caracteres** | amostra |
| p | Endereço do ponteiro | b8000000 |
| n | Nada impresso. |  |
| % | Um % seguido por outro caractere % gravará um único % no fluxo. | % |

<sup>Fonte: [www.cplusplus.com](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)</sup>

Então segundo essa tabela:

- quando quiser imprimir apenas um caractere use o especificador de formato `%c`.
- quando quiser imprimir sequencia de caracteres(string) use o especificador de formato `%s`.

#### Adendo.

Considerando a hipótese de que ainda não possa usar o laço `for` e o exercício exija que seja configurado individualmente cada caractere do array ainda tem a solução a seguir, mesmo sendo prolixa funciona.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TAM 5

int main (int argc, char**argv){

  char vogal[TAM + 1] = "";                              //Declara a string vazia reservando um espaço para o terminador.
  vogal[0] = 'a';
  vogal[1] = 'e';
  vogal[2] = 'i';
  vogal[3] = 'o';
  vogal[4] = 'u';
    
  printf("\n\n\t Mostrando os valores dos vetores \n");
  printf("\n Posição 0: %c",vogal[0]);                   //Imprimeo caractere usando especificador de formato %c.
  printf("\n Posição 1: %c",vogal[1]);
  printf("\n Posição 2: %c",vogal[2]);
  printf("\n Posição 3: %c",vogal[3]);
  printf("\n Posição 4: %c",vogal[4]);
}
```

Comment: Olá, Muito obrigado pela ajuda!!! Consegui entender de forma objetiva onde eu estava tendo dificuldade graças a isso. Muito Agradecido.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o principal problema no seu caso foi utilizar na função `printf` o especificador de formato `%s` que é o adequado para imprimir variáveis do tipo vetor de caracteres e não para um único caracter de cada vez como é o caso. Para imprimir o tipo `char` o correto é utilizar o especificador `%c`.

Restringindo o escopo do problema à impressão de variáveis do tipo `char` com a função `printf`, resolvemos o problema utilizando `%c` ao invés de `%s` como no exemplo abaixo:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char teste = 'a';
    
    //na forma incorreta abaixo é gerado um erro
    //printf("Impressao incorreta = %s", teste);
    
    //a linha abaixo compila corretamente e gera a saída "Impressao correta = a"
    printf("Impressao correta = %c", teste);
}
```

Aplicando somente a correção do erro de impressão e desprezando demais erros de indentação, sintaxe e semântica temos a versão abaixo do código da pergunta:

```c
int main (int argc, char**argv){

char vogal[TAM];
int cont;

vogal[0] = 'a';
vogal[1] = 'e';
vogal[2] = 'i';
vogal[3] = 'o';
vogal[4] = 'u';


/*Lendo */
printf("\n\n\t Mostrando os valores dos vetores \n");
printf("\n Posição 0: %c",vogal[0]);
printf("\n Posição 1: %c",vogal[1]);
printf("\n Posição 2: %c",vogal[2]);
printf("\n Posição 2: %c",vogal[3]);
printf("\n Posição 2: %c",vogal[4]);
}
```

Essa referência possui uma tabela de especificadores para a função `printf` que pode ajudar: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: Leia na [resposta que escrevi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/550586/137387) que quando faz isso aqui `char vogal[TAM];` o padrão C não define um comportamento padrão de inicialização de variáveis e memória de processo, então em alguns compiladores isso **APARENTEMENTE** funciona pois antes de iniciar a aplicação eles preenchem o stack com zeros(*'\0'*) então após a string mal declara haverá um terminador, porém outros compiladores não fazem esse preenchimento gerando cadeias de caracteres corrompidas.

Comment: Veja o teste do seu código num compilador que zera o stack antes iniciar a aplicação: https://ideone.com/hh7RFh , irá *aparentar* que está mas não está se mudarmos o seu código para o heap onde a memória não é previamente inicializada inicializada a string se mostrará corrompida, veja: https://ideone.com/aK6Cnn

Comment: Veja o teste do seu código num compilador que não zera o stack antes de iniciar a aplicação: https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/strings a string irá aparecer corrompida.

Comment: @AugustoVasques entendo a preocupação com o caractere finalizador para o caso de impressão no formato de cadeia de caracteres, seu ponto é perfeito. Apenas tentei limitar minha resposta ao escopo de "entender porque a tela de execução não mostra os valores" que entendi ser o problema apontado, por tentar realizar a impressão do tipo char com o especificador %s

Comment: Eu entendo isso tanto que que não negativei, mas muita gente vem aqui e apenas copia e cola os códigos das repostas, sem fazer testes e verificações. Quando der uma resposta que contiver erro ou conceito equivocado deixe claro para que o erro não seja propagado, veja o meu caso eu tinha como avaliar se você tinha conhecimento ou não de que strings c terminam em null. (Desculpe o corretor está me fazendo passar por analfabeto).