# Erro de indentação em Python

Tags: python

Sou novo em Python e estou fazendo um projeto... no entanto fui executar este e deu um erro na linha 44, cuja mensagem é:

> IndentationError: expected an indented block

```
    import blockchain, threading, requests

coins_API = ["https://www.mercadobitcoin.net/api/BTC/ticker/", "www.exemplo.com", "www.exemplo.com"]
cc_names = ["Bitcoin", "Litecoin", "Etherum"]
btc_prices = []
ltc_prices = []
eth_prices = []

class wallet:
    def start():
        print("Starting BitBot!")

        prices.start()

        WALLETID = raw_input("Insert the Wallet ID: ")
        PASSWORD = raw_input("Insert your passoword: ")
        HOST = "https://blockchain.info"

        #checking_coin_prices.start()
        wallet_conn(WALLETID, PASSWORD, HOST)

    def wallet_conn(WALLETID, PASSWORD, HOST):
        try:
            print("Trying the connection with the wallet: ")
            current_wallet = wallet(WALLETID, PASSWORD, HOST)
        except:
            print("Login Unknown error!")

class prices:
    def start():
        print("Searching for prices!")
        while 1:
            for i in range(0, len(cc_names)):
                if i == 0:
                    btc_prices.append(get_cc_price())
                if i == 1:
                    ltc_prices.append(get_cc_price())
                if i == 2:
                    eth_prices.append(get_cc_price())

            if btc_prices >= eth_prices:
                #To do buy and sell prices!

    def get_cc_price(): #Erro de identação aqui! <-----------------------------
        for i in range(0, len(cc_names)):
            print("Checking the {} price!", .format(cc_names[i]))
            try:
                cc_price = requests.get(coins_API[i])
                print(cc_price.status_code)
                print(cc_price.json())
                if i == 0:
                    return conversions.usd_to_brl(cc_price["last"])
                else:
                    return conversions,usd_to_brl(cc_price)
            except:
                print("Error while checking the {} price!", .format(cc_names[i]))
                return 0

class conversions:
    def usd_to_brl(cc_usd_price):
        print("Converting the cryptocoin price!")
        try:
            brl_price = requests.get("")
            print(brl_price.status_code)
            return cc_usd_price * brl_price
        except:
            print("Error while converting the cryptocoin price!")
            return 0

#checking_coin_prices = threading.Thread(target=prices.start)

wallet.start()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Veja as linhas 41 e 42:

```
if btc_prices >= eth_prices:
    #To do buy and sell prices!
```

Aqui você tem um [bloco condicional](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements) e não faz nada dentro dele. Está vazio. Apenas um [comentário](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#an-informal-introduction-to-python) dentro.

Não sei qual era sua intenção, mas faça qualquer coisa que seja lá dentro. O statement `pass` pode resolver nesse caso.

```
if btc_prices >= eth_prices:
    pass 
    #HACK(código provisório!)
```

> O `pass` é uma palavra que deve ser usada sempre que o programa requisitar sintaticamente que se preencha uma lacuna [...]

Essa citação foi pega [daqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/323/41056).

Algumas perguntas aqui do SOpt que achei útil e falam sobre o `pass`:

- [Quais são outras aplicações de pass?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/247665/quais-s%C3%A3o-outras-aplica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-pass)
- [Qual a diferença entre break, pass e continue em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/322/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-break-pass-e-continue-em-python)

Comment: Obrigado amigo! O código funcionou perfeitamente!