# Quais são outras aplicações de pass?

Tags: python, sintaxe

Na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/pass.html) o *statement* `pass` é definido

> `pass` é uma operação nula. Quando executado, nada acontece. É útil como um *placeholder* quando sintaticamente um *statement* é requerido, mas nenhum código precisa ser executado.

Isso é, ele é útil quando tenho algo assim:

```
if aprovou_pagamento(p):
    pass
    # TODO(efetivar transação)
else:
    desefetivar_transacao(p.transacao)
```

pois isto geraria um erro de sintaxe:

```
if aprovou_pagamento(p):
    # TODO(efetivar transação)
else:
    desefetivar_transacao(p.transacao)
```

Fora isso, não consigo enxergar nenhuma aplicação prática, a não ser nessas condições.

Existem outras aplicações para o `pass`? Em que outros contextos ele seria útil?

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual a real utilidade do pass neste caso?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/240994/5878)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É só isto mesmo, claro que pode usar em vários lugares, não só um `if`.

Um caso interessante é quando deseja criar um um método abstrato, ou seja sem implementação naquele tipo, provavelmente para ser implementado em um tipo herdado, para não dar erro coloca o `pass` no corpo dele.