# Como gerar condição de interrupção de um laço de repetição no Python durante sua execução?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estou tentando fazer um programa no Python que durante a execução de um laço de repetição, algum comando fique aguardando uma condição de entrada enquanto o *loop* é executado.

Por exemplo, um programa que imprima na tela números, em ordem crescente e de 1 em 1 segundo, a partir de zero enquanto espera o usuário digitar uma string "encerra". Quando tal string for lida, o laço é interrompido e para de imprimir os números na tela.

Tentei fazer assim, mas não deu certo:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time

i = 0
mensagem = 0
while mensagem!='terminar':
    mensagem = str(raw_input())
    if mensagem=='terminar':
        print "encerrado"
    else:
        print i
        time.sleep(1)
        i+=1
```

Comment: Ler e escrever no console ao mesmo tempo dificilmente é uma boa ideia. Melhor você criar uma interface gráfica, conforme sugerido pelo nosklo.

Answer (score 2):

O seu problema é que a função `raw_input()` "bloqueia" (blocks) - isto é - ele fica esperando a entrada do usuário e não retorna enquanto não vier essa entrada. O programa para ali! `time.sleep()` também só retorna quando o tempo passar.

Pra contornar isso, uma das formas é verificar antes de chamar `raw_input()` se existe dados a serem lidos. No python podemos usar o módulo `select`. Ele espera, por um determinado tempo em segundos, verificando se tem dados disponíveis para serem lidos. Se tiverem dados, ele retorna imediatamente, caso contrário só retorna ao passar o tempo especificado.

import sys
import select

```
i = 0

while True:
    print i
    pode_ler = select.select([sys.stdin,],[],[], 1)[0]
    if pode_ler and raw_input().strip().lower() == 'terminar':
        break
    i+=1
```

Note que isso só funciona no linux. No windows, `select` só funciona com sockets, então uma solução simples como esta não é possível - seria necessário usar uma thread encaminhando dados para um socket "selectável".

Porém programas sérios que leem dados de `stdin` enquanto fazem outra coisa no windows são raros, então isso não é muito importante. Se precisa ler dados enquanto exibe outra coisa, sugiro já começar a fazer uma interface gráfica para seu programa, usando uma biblioteca de programação visual como o tkinter - neste caso o seu programa responderá a eventos como o clique de um botão para finalizar.

Answer (score 0):

Seu código já está quase atendendo, só falta uma instrução `break`, no bloco do `if`, simples assim, você já "quebraria" o laço de repetição quando a condição fosse alcançada.

E o bloco do `while` ficaria mais lógico se o valor ficasse em `True` por padrão, garantindo a repetição.

```
    #-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time

i = 0
mensagem = 0
while True:
    mensagem = str(raw_input())
    if mensagem=='terminar':
        print "encerrado"
        break
    else:
        print i
        time.sleep(1)
        i+=1
```

Algumas fontes:

[Qual a diferença entre break, pass e continue em Python?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/322/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-break-pass-e-continue-em-python)

https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/break.html