# Fazer o input aceitar somente números positivos

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um programa que calcula fatoriais, que já está rodando direito.

Porém não sei como fazer o `input` desse programa aceitar apenas números positivos. Tentei com `isdigit`:

```
n = int(input('Digite um numero para calcular seu fatorial ' ))
if not n.isdigit():
    print("Digite apenas numeros!")
c = n
f = 1
print('Calculando {}! = '.format(n), end='')
while c > 0:
    print('{}'.format(c),end='')
    print(' x ' if c > 1 else ' = ',end='')
    f *= c
    c -= 1
print('{}'.format(f))
```

Mas ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Python\files\nap1\q2.py", line 18, in <module>
    if not n.isdigit():
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'
```

Comment: Nada disso faz sentido. Se quer um número e que ele seja positivo, então é só verificar se é maior ou igual a 0. Se quer garantir que o que foi digitado seja um número em Python costuma ser através de captura de exceção. Se a primeira linha não lançar exceção é porque ele é composto por um número válido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá removes a conversão para INT inicial e fazes a conversão depois de validares....assim:

```
n = input('Digite um numero para calcular seu fatorial ' )
if not n.isdigit():
    print("Digite apenas numeros!")
else:
    c = int(n)
    f = 1
    print('Calculando {}! = '.format(n), end='')
    while c > 0:
        print('{}'.format(c),end='')
        print(' x ' if c > 1 else ' = ',end='')
        f *= c
        c -= 1
    print('{}'.format(f))
```

Answer (score 0):

Vamos por partes:

- [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) converte uma string para um número, mas caso não consiga, lança um [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError). Então se o código chegou no `if not n.isdigit():`, é porque `int(input(...))` deu certo e converteu a string corretamente para número. Ou seja, nesse ponto não faz mais sentido testar se é de fato um número.
- [`isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) é um método de strings, mas você tentou usá-lo com um número (pois `n` é o retorno de `int`).

Mas mesmo se você arrumar esses problemas, ainda sim a lógica está errada. Repare que se não for número, ele entra no `if`, imprime a mensagem *"Digite apenas numeros!"*, mas depois ele continua executando o restante do código (ou seja, ele vai tentar calcular o fatorial, independente de `n` ser um número ou não). Não faz sentido tentar executar o cálculo se já sabemos que `n` não é um número válido.

Então você poderia mudar para algo assim:

```
try:
    n = int(input('Digite um numero para calcular seu fatorial: '))
    if n < 0:
        print('Número deve ser maior ou igual a zero')
    else:
        # aqui você calcula o fatorial de n
except ValueError:
    print('Você não digitou um número')
```

Se não for digitado um número, `int` lança o `ValueError` e ele cai no bloco `except`.

Se `int` der certo (ou seja, foi digitado um número), você testa se ele é menor que zero (e se for, imprime a mensagem correspondente).
Se não for (ou seja, o número é maior ou igual a zero), ele cai no `else` (e dentro desse `else` você coloca o código para calcular o fatorial de `n`).

---

Outra opção é ficar pedindo para o usuário digitar o número até que ele seja válido (ou seja, até que ele seja maior ou igual a zero). Enquanto não for, você pede que digite de novo:

```
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input('Digite um numero para calcular seu fatorial: '))
        if n < 0:
            print('Número deve ser maior ou igual a zero')
        else:
            break # sai do loop
    except ValueError:
        print('Você não digitou um número')

# aqui (fora do while) você calcula o fatorial de n
```

O `while True:` cria um *loop* infinito, que só é interrompido quando o número é maior ou igual a zero (o `break` dentro do `else` [interrompe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/322/112052) o `while`).

Depois, fora do `while` você coloca o cálculo do fatorial de `n`, pois já garantimos que nesse ponto ele é um número maior ou igual a zero.

---

A outra resposta usa [`isdigit`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/411720/112052) para verificar se foi digitado um número. De fato, para os casos mais simples funciona, mas há caracteres que retornam `True` mas mesmo assim dão erro na hora de converter com `int()`. Um exemplo é o caractere `²` ([SUPERSCRIPT TWO](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b2/index.htm)) - repare que ele é um "2", só que menor e colocado "pra cima" (é usado por exemplo para escrever números ao quadrado - ex: 3² = 9). [Veja aqui um exemplo no IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/hRvloh).

Além disso, se for digitado algo como    `2`    (com espaços antes e depois do `2`), `isdigit()` retorna `False`, mas a conversão com `int()` funciona ([veja aqui](https://ideone.com/T0uO8L)). Então provavelmente para este caso o melhor seja tentar usar `int()` diretamente e capturar o `ValueError` (ou então usar o [método `strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) para remover esses espaços).