# Limitar quantidade de números em um input

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um programa básico que inverte números (se o usuário digita 123, o programa retorna 321), porém o usuário pode digitar apenas 3 números, se passar disso o programa tem que pedir para o usuário digitar novamente o valor.

```
na = input('Digite 3 números')
an = na [::-1]
print('o valor invertido é',an)
```

Quero saber o que devo usar para limitar a quantidade de números no `input`.

Comment: *"o usuário pode digitar apenas 3 números"* - isso quer dizer *exatamente* 3 ou *no máximo* 3? (sei que parece besteira, e pela resposta aceita, *parece* que é no máximo 3 mesmo, mas tente não deixar o texto ambíguo, caso contrário as pessoas só vão acertar a resposta "no chute").

Comment: E se for digitado `001`, isso corresponde ao número 1, então o inverso deve ser `1` ou `100`? Esse é outro detalhe que parece besta e pedante, mas é importante saber se vc quer inverter os caracteres digitados - desde que eles sejam dígitos - ou se quer inverter os dígitos do valor numérico (que na maioria dos casos é a mesma coisa, mas no caso do `001` faz diferença)

Comment: Da maneira que está hoje descrito deverá aceitar exatamente 3 dígitos e o valor `001` não deveria ser aceito, pois pede para inverter números, não *strings* numéricas; numericamente falando `001` é 1 e só possui um dígito.

Comment: Natanael, aproveitando, tudo que eu disse abaixo sobre `isdigit` também vale para [outra pergunta sua](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/411714/112052) (ali também pode dar erro, dependendo do que for digitado, já que vc usa `int` se `isdigit` retornar `True`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>*Sei que é um "programa básico" que você provavelmente está fazendo para treinar (ou apenas um exercício que lhe foi passado), mas de qualquer forma é uma oportunidade para discutir e se aprofundar em alguns pontos.*</sup>

---

Dada a descrição do problema:

> Estou fazendo um programa básico que inverte números (se o usuário digita 123, o programa retorna 321), porém o usuário pode digitar apenas 3 números.

Ou seja, primeiro o usuário digita algo. Então você verifica se esse algo é um número com apenas 3 dígitos e os inverte.

Aí vem a primeira dúvida: o texto dá a entender que o número deve ter **exatamente** 3 dígitos, certo? Ou é **no máximo** 3 dígitos? Dependendo do que for, a solução será diferente.

Por exemplo, se quer validar que é um número que tem **exatamente** 3 dígitos, uma opção é fazer assim:

```
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input('digite um número de 3 dígitos: '))
        if 100 <= n <= 999: # é um número de 3 dígitos
            break
        print('O número deve ter 3 dígitos')
    except ValueError:
        print('Não foi digitado um número')

# calcula o inverso (fora do while)
```

Ou seja, primeiro eu tento converter o que foi digitado para número, usando [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int). Se não foi digitado um número, ele lança um [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) e o código cai no `except`, exibindo a respectiva mensagem. Então o *loop* continua, pedindo para digitar novamente.

Se foi digitado um número, basta ver se ele está entre 100 e 999 (ou seja, se é um número de exatamente 3 dígitos). Nesse caso, ele entra no `if`, e o `break` [interrompe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/322/112052) o *loop* `while`. Depois, fora do `while`, você inverte os dígitos do número (mais abaixo veremos como fazer isso).

---

Mas se você quer um número com **no máximo** 3 dígitos, aí o teste poderia ser `if n <= 999`. Se bem que esse teste também considera que o zero é válido. Ah, e também considera números negativos, então talvez devesse ser `if 0 < n <= 999`, assim somente os números maiores que zero são válidos. Mas `-123` também não é um número de 3 dígitos? Nesse caso, a condição deveria ser `if 100 <= abs(n) <= 999` (a [função `abs()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs) retorna o valor do número sem sinal, assim podemos considerar números negativos também). Qual desses usar? Depende do que você precisa, e de quais casos vai considerar como válidos.

Parece um detalhe besta e sem importância (*"cara, é só um exercício, tanto faz"*), mas quando for programar sistemas reais, detalhes assim podem fazer toda a diferença. Imagine um sistema de pagamento que em determinadas condições só aceita exatamente 3 parcelas, mas você faz um código que aceita no máximo 3 (ou vice-versa). Ou um código que aceita zero ou `-10` parcelas (faz sentido a quantidade de parcelas ser negativa?). De um detalhe besta, isso passa a ser um erro grave, que pode dar problemas na hora que os usuários forem efetuar os pagamentos. Então quando um cliente disser que "meu sistema deve aceitar pagamentos em apenas 3 parcelas", não custa nada perguntar se ele quis dizer "exatamente 3" ou "no máximo 3". Sei que é "só um exercício", mas exercícios também servem para... exercitar o raciocínio e também o *mindset*, e pensar nesses casos especiais, exceções, situações estranhas que podem dar errado e tudo mais, tudo isso faz parte da vida profissional na nossa área, então é importante se acostumar a pensar assim desde já.

Bom, uma vez definido o critério para considerar o que é um número válido (escolha o que fizer mais sentido, dependendo do contexto), vamos ver como invertê-lo.

---

#### Invertendo os dígitos

Aqui cabe um parênteses para falar de dois conceitos: valor e representação do valor.

Um número é uma ideia, um conceito: ele representa um valor... numérico, que pode corresponder a várias coisas diferentes, dependendo do contexto (entre os usos mais comuns, temos quantidades, pontuação, medidas, mas há também os números negativos que podem representar uma dívida ou saldo negativo, etc). O número 5, por exemplo, representa a ideia de um valor específico (cinco "coisas" quaisquer).

Mas esse mesmo valor (o `5`) pode ser representado **textualmente** de diferentes maneiras: como o dígito "5", como "5.0", como os textos "cinco", "five" (em inglês), "五" (em japonês), etc. Todas essas formas são representações diferentes do mesmo número (do mesmo valor).

Dito isso, o que exatamente você quer inverter? O valor numérico, ou a representação textual desse valor numérico (a string contendo os dígitos que representam aquele número)?

Se o usuário digitar `001`, por exemplo, você considera que são 3 dígitos? Se estivermos pensando em termos de "representação textual do valor numérico" (ou seja, uma string em determinado formato que representa um número), então podemos considerar que sim, a string `"001"` contém 3 dígitos (e nesse caso, bastaria usar [`len(string)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) para saber a quantidade de dígitos - além de métodos como `isnumeric()` ou `isdigit()` para verificar se são números, sobre os quais já falaremos a respeito mais abaixo). E neste caso, ao inverter os dígitos (usando `string[::-1]`, como já foi sugerido), o resultado seria `100`.

Mas se estivermos pensando em termos de valores numéricos (independente da sua representação textual), então `001` na verdade corresponde ao número 1 (seu valor numérico é 1, independente de sua representação textual). E 1 não é um número de 3 dígitos, então dependendo do critério escolhido acima (exatamente 3 ou no máximo 3), ele pode ou não ser aceito como um número válido. E caso seja válido, ao inverter os dígitos de 1, o resultado também seria 1.

Ou seja, o que você quer inverter de fato? Se for **o texto digitado pelo usuário** (desde que o texto só tenha números), então bastaria adaptar o que foi feito na [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/411873/112052):

```
while True:
    try:
        texto = input('digite um número de 3 dígitos: ')
        if texto.isnumeric() and len(texto) == 3: # é um "número" de 3 dígitos
            break # sai do loop
        print('O número deve ter 3 dígitos')
    except ValueError:
        print('Não foi digitado um número')

print(texto[::-1]) # imprime invertido
```

No caso, estou considerando que você escolheu como critério "tem exatamente 3 dígitos". O código acima considera que `001` invertido é `100`, e `1` ou `01` são inválidos.

Mas se você quer considerar o **valor numérico** (e não o texto exato que o usuário digitou), aí é diferente:

```
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input('digite um número de 3 dígitos: '))
        if 100 <= n <= 999: # é um número de 3 dígitos
            break # sai do loop
        print('O número deve ter 3 dígitos')
    except ValueError:
        print('Não foi digitado um número')

# invertendo
inverso = 0
while n > 0:
    inverso = inverso * 10 + n % 10
    n //= 10

print(inverso)
```

Pois é, eu inverti os dígitos usando um algoritmo matemático, em vez de converter o número para string e inverter. A diferença se dá em casos como `100`, cujo inverso será `1` (e não `001`, pois estou considerando o valor numérico, e não a sua representação textual, e por isso os zeros à esquerda são irrelevantes).

Mas caso você queira inverter números negativos (`-123` resulta em `-321`, e `-100` resulta em `-1`), basta mudar o `if` dentro do `while` para `if 100 <= abs(n) <= 999` (como já explicado acima) e algoritmo de inversão para:

```
x = abs(n)
inverso = 0
while x > 0:
    inverso = inverso * 10 + x % 10
    x //= 10
if n < 0:
    inverso *= -1
```

---

Então qual a resposta certa afinal? Da forma que a pergunta foi feita, é discutível (tanto que as outras respostas entenderam uma coisa, mas [nos comentários entenderam outra](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/411862/limitar-quantidade-de-n%c3%bameros-em-um-input-em-python#comment804133_411862)), e resolvi deixar várias opções justamente para mostrar que o primeiro passo para ter um programa correto é definir bem o problema, os requisitos, o que pode e o que não pode, como devem ser as entradas e saídas, etc. Mesmo que seja "só um exercício", "só um programinha para treinar", se não definir muito bem o que quer fazer, nenhuma resposta será certa (ou qualquer coisa servirá, já que "tanto faz").

---

#### Sobre `isnumeric`

Foi sugerido usar o [método `isnumeric()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric) para verificar se a string possui apenas números. De fato, se o usuário digitar coisas como `123` e `000`, este método funciona. Mas o problema é que ele é bem abrangente, e não considera apenas os dígitos de 0 a 9. Existem [vários caracteres](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm) definidos pelo [Unicode](https://home.unicode.org) que `isnumeric()` também considera como "números" ([veja aqui](https://ideone.com/K4R1Fd)), mas que não necessariamente formarão um número com 3 dígitos (`int()` lançará um `ValueError`, mesmo com `isnumeric()` retornando `True`).

Um exemplo é o caractere `½` ([VULGAR FRACTION ONE HALF](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00bd/index.htm)), que com `isnumeric()` retorna `True`, mas ao converter para número com `int()`, dá erro:

```
print('½'.isnumeric()) # True
print(int('½')) # ValueError
```

<sup>[Veja aqui](https://ideone.com/V4deX0) este código rodando.</sup>

Ou seja, dependendo de como você quer fazer seu código (considerar o valor numérico ou a representação textual), usar uma ou outra abordagem pode dar resultados diferentes: se usar `isnumeric()` com a string `'½'` e invertê-la com `texto[::-1]`, "funciona", se tentar convertê-la para número usando `int()`, dá erro. Novamente, sei que "é só um exercício", mas se o usuário pode digitar qualquer coisa, seu programa tem que estar preparado para validar e só prosseguir se tiver dados válidos.

Outra opção seria usar o [método `isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit), que é um pouco menos abrangente que `isnumeric()` (por exemplo, `'½'.isdigit()` retorna `False`). Só que também há casos em que `isdigit()` retorna `True` mas a conversão com `int()` dá erro, como por exemplo com o caractere `²` ([SUPERSCRIPT TWO](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b2/index.htm)) - repare que ele é um "2", só que menor e colocado "pra cima" (é usado por exemplo para escrever números ao quadrado - ex: 3² = 9):

```
print('½'.isdigit()) # False
print('²'.isdigit()) # True
print(int('²')) # ValueError
```

<sup>[Veja aqui](https://ideone.com/7grNKB) este código rodando.</sup>

Ou seja, dependendo do que você definir como "dígitos", de qual a quantidade destes pode ser aceita (exatamente X ou no máximo X) e do que você quer inverter (o valor numérico ou "o texto exato que o usuário digitou"), a solução será diferente. As outras respostas invertem qualquer coisa (**nenhuma delas está verificando se foi digitado somente números, que para mim é um dos pontos principais da pergunta, e consequentemente da solução**) e além disso aceitam uma string vazia (quando o usuário só dá um <kbd>ENTER</kbd> no `input()`) e mostram os "dígitos invertidos" da string vazia (ou seja, mostram a mensagem `O valor invertido é` ).

Talvez eu esteja sendo rígido demais e "*é só um exercício, não precisa disso*", mas novamente digo que é importante pensar nesses casos, pois em sistemas reais isso é algo que terá que pensar sempre. Então se acostume desde já a validar os dados que recebe, ainda mais se o usuário pode digitar qualquer coisa. E sempre consulte a documentação e entenda a implicação de usar quaisquer funções/métodos/APIs, pois como pode ver, usar `isdigit()`, `isnumeric()` ou `int()` pode dar resultados diferentes, dependendo do caso.

Outro exemplo é quando há espaços antes ou depois dos números.
Por exemplo, se o usuário digita    `123`   . Se usar `isnumeric()` ou `isdigit()`, o resultado será `False`, mas se usar `int()`, ele converte corretamente para o número 123 ([veja aqui](https://ideone.com/T0uO8L)). Claro que dá para corrigir isso usando [`texto.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip), que remove esses espaços, mas esse é mais um caso que as outras respostas não tratam (se o usuário digitar 3 espaços, elas aceitam e invertem a string mesmo assim).

---

No fim, tudo isso é para dizer que sempre dá para complicar, e que você [não pode confiar em nada que o usuário digita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/112052), e é interessante que seu programa esteja preparado para lidar com dados indesejados/inválidos. Claro que você não vai escrever validações para **todos** os casos possíveis e imagináveis, mas aceitar qualquer coisa também não dá. Se o programa quer inverter números, o mínimo que você deve fazer é verificar se foi digitado um número.

Comment: Nossa, eu não sabia que o isnumeric() retornava True também para outros caracteres kkk. Acabou que sua resposta também me mostrou coisas novas xD

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 Se o mundo fosse só em ASCII, tudo seria mais simples, né? Depois que inventaram o Unicode, nenhum código que lida com caracteres é óbvio... :-(

Answer (score 1):

Utilize a função `len(seq)`. Essa função conta quantos elementos uma sequência (strings,listas,tuplas,etc...) possui, exemplo:

```
while True:
    nums = input(" Digite 3 números:")
    if len(nums) > 3:
        print(" Você deve digitar somente 3 números!")
        continue
    break
print("O valor invertido é %s."%nums[::-1])
```

## Detalhe extra:

Esse programa não impede o usuário de digitar letras e outros caracteres que não sejam números. Então se quiser, você pode usar o método `isnumeric()` para saber se a entrada do usuário possui somente números.

Comment: Esta resposta está errada, não está obrigando digitar 3 dígitos.  É triste ver uma resposta claramente errada aceita como se fosse certa. Fazer errado e dizer que pode fazer certo não torna a resposta certa.

Comment: Me desculpe, mas eu não entendi onde a resposta está errada. O que ele queria era uma forma de garantir que o usuário digitasse no máximo 3 números. Eu testei o código da resposta e está funcionando tudo certinho. O detalhe extra que deixei aí é para ele melhorar o código caso queira impedir que o usuário digite outras coisas que não sejam números. Se você puder me apontar o erro da resposta, eu realmente agradeço.