# média de valores digitados no input em python

Tags: python

Estou fazendo um programa que pega um valor digitado no `input` (que não seja negativo e seja menor que 20) e calcula:

- a) O maior valor;
- b) O menor valor;
- c) A soma dos valores;
- d) A média aritmética dos valores;
- e) A quantidade de números pares;
- f) A quantidade de números impares.

Eu já fiz a parte do maior, menor e soma, porém não sei como pegar a média, pares e ímpares.

```
valor = input('Digite um número menor que 20 que seja positivo: ') #pede para um usuário digitar um número
if not valor.isdigit():
    print('Digite apenas números positivos!')
else:
    maximo = max(valor)
    minimo = min(valor)
    soma = 0
    for valor in valor: #verifica elemento a elemento dentro de um for e faz a soma dessa lista
        soma += int(valor)
    print('O maior valor é:',maximo)
    print('O menor valor é:',minimo)
    print('A soma é:',soma)
    print('A média é:',media)
```

Gostaria de saber como devo proceder para restringir, de maneira eficiente, os valores digitados pelo usuário para apenas valores inteiros entre `"1"` e `"19"`, ou seja, quero que o programa só avance se o usuário digitar valores entre `"1"` e `"19"` e, caso contrário, exiba um erro e solicite `novamente` um valor coerente.

Comment: Natanael, a media seria o número digitado, dividido pela quantidade de dígitos? Como pretende calcular a média?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Natanael, para pegar o número válido, você terá que manter o usuário em um loop (while) até que ele digite algo válido.

A média, pode ser feita de duas formas seguindo o seu código, dividindo o número ou a soma pela quantidade de dígitos.

Para saber se um número é ímpar ou par, costuma-se verificar o resto da divisão por dois, restando zero, trata-se de um número par.

Abaixo um exemplo dessas implementações, sendo que para pegar o número e verificar se é ímpar ou par, foram criadas funções:

```
#Função que pega o número e valida o mesmo, se não atender as condições, pede novamente o número e não sai do laço
def pegarNumero():
  invalido = True
  valor = ''

  while invalido:
    valor = input('Digite um número menor que 20 que seja positivo: ') #pede para um usuário digitar um número

    if not valor.isdigit():
      print('Digite apenas números positivos!')
    elif int(valor) >= 20:
      print('Digite apenas números menores que 20!')
    else:
      invalido = False

  return valor

#Função que retorna se o número é ímpar ou par, utilizando o resto da divisão por dois
def parImpar(numero):
  if numero % 2 == 0:
    return 'par'
  else:
    return 'ímpar'


valor = pegarNumero()

maximo = max(valor)
minimo = min(valor)
soma = 0

#Quantidade de dígitos que o número digitado possui
quantidadeNumeros = len(valor)
#Valor digitado já convertido, apenas para evitar diversas conversões
valorNumerico = int(valor)
media = valorNumerico / quantidadeNumeros
imparPar = parImpar(valorNumerico)

for numero in valor: #verifica elemento a elemento dentro de um for e faz a soma dessa lista
  soma += int(numero)

print('O maior valor é:',maximo)
print('O menor valor é:',minimo)
print('A soma é:',soma)

#Você pode calcular a média também, dividindo a soma pela quantidade de dígitos no número:
#print('A média é:',soma / quantidadeNumeros)
print('A média é:',media)

print(f'O número {valor} é {imparPar}')

#Só exibe para números maior ou igual a dez, caso contrário o print acima já exibiu
if len(valor) >= 2:
  for numero in valor:
    numeroParOuImpar = parImpar(int(numero))
    print(f'O número {numero} é {numeroParOuImpar}')
```

As duas formas de calcular a média estão no exemplo, mas uma delas está comentada, espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>*A pergunta dá a entender que você quer percorrer **os dígitos de um número**, ver qual o maior e o menor, somá-los e calcular a média. Então vamos lá...*</sup>

---

Na sua [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/411862/112052) eu já [respondi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/412148/112052) sobre o uso de [`isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) para verificar se uma string contém um número.

Basicamente, se o usuário pode digitar qualquer coisa, então nada impede que ele digite caracteres como o `²` ([SUPERSCRIPT TWO](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b2/index.htm)), que retorna `True` para `isdigit()`, mas ao tentar convertê-lo para número com [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int), dá erro:

```
print('²'.isdigit()) # True
print(int('²')) # ValueError
```

<sup>[Veja aqui](https://ideone.com/7grNKB) este código rodando</sup>

Pode ser um *corner case* "raro", que "nunca vai acontecer", mas a princípio [você não deve confiar em nada que o usuário digita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13298/112052), e sempre validar o que recebe. E no seu caso, se usar `isdigit` e depois tentar converter para número com `int`, há casos em que pode dar erro. [Veja aqui](https://ideone.com/ctAEXQ) todos os caracteres que caem nesta situação.

---

Então se quer verificar se uma string contém um número, em vez de usar `isdigit()`, tente convertê-la usando `int()` e capture o [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) (para os casos em que a conversão para número der erro):

```
def ler_numero():
    while True:
        try:
            n = int(input('Digite um número menor que 20 que seja positivo: '))
            if 0 < n < 20:
                return n # se o valor está correto, retorna
            else:
                print('O número deve ser positivo e menor que 20')
        except ValueError: # não foi digitado um número
            print('Digite um número válido')
```

Esta função tem um *loop* infinito (`while True`) que só é interrompido se for digitado um número positivo menor que 20 (o `return` sai da função e retorna o valor como um número).

Claro que usar `isdigit()` e depois `int()` também funciona para a maioria dos casos, mas se você vai ter que verificar se o número é menor que 20, por que não tentar usar `int` logo de cara? O uso de `isdigit()` se torna redundante, pois se a string não for um número, eu já consigo detectar isso no bloco `except`. Então no fim nem precisa de `isdigit()`.

Em seguida, basta usar esta função para ler o número, fazer um *loop* pelos seus dígitos e calcular o que precisa:

```
n = ler_numero()

maior = -1
menor = 10
soma = 0
qtd = 0
pares = 0
impares = 0
while n > 0:
    digito = n % 10
    if digito > maior:
        maior = digito
    if digito < menor:
        menor = digito

    if digito % 2 == 0:
        pares += 1
    else:
        impares += 1

    soma += digito
    qtd += 1
    n //= 10

media = soma / qtd
```

No caso, eu faço um `while` considerando o valor numérico, pego o último dígito usando o resto da divisão por 10 (`n % 10`), comparo esse dígito com o maior e menor valor atual, atualizo a soma e a quantidade de dígitos (além da quantidade de pares e ímpares - bastando verificar o resto da divisão por 2 para saber se é par ou ímpar). Por fim, divido o número por 10, pois na próxima iteração do laço ele pegará o penúltimo dígito, e assim por diante, até percorrer todos os dígitos do número.

Repare que, como estou comparando dígitos, eu sei que eles sempre estarão entre 0 e 9, por isso o `maior` é inicializado com `-1` e `menor` com `10` (a ideia é inicializar com um valor que seja respectivamente menor e maior que todos os valores possíveis, garantindo que o algoritmo sempre encontre o maior e o menor valor dentre os existentes).

Essa abordagem é diferente da sua, pois como já expliquei [em outra resposta (à outra pergunta sua já citada)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/412148/112052), existe uma diferença entre o valor numérico e a representação desse valor numérico. Por exemplo, se o usuário digitar `02`, a string contém 2 dígitos, mas o valor numérico é 2 (um número com apenas um dígito).

Se você usar o seu algoritmo (ou o proposto [na outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/413199/112052)), será considerado que o número possui dois dígitos, o menor é zero, e a média é 1. Já se usar o meu algoritmo acima, o número possui apenas um dígito, portanto o menor é 2 e a média também é 2.
Qual está certo? **Depende** do que você quer: se vai considerar o valor numérico, use o código acima. Se vai considerar a representação textual do valor numérico (a exata string digitada pelo usuário), use o código [da outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/413199/112052).

---

Outra diferença é que o algoritmo acima só percorre os dígitos do número uma única vez, enquanto a outra solução percorre várias vezes. As chamadas a [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) e [`min`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min), por exemplo: cada uma percorre todos os dígitos, então você está fazendo 2 *loops* (só porque você não fez um *loop* explícito, não quer dizer que não há um sendo feito em outro lugar). Depois você ainda faz outro *loop* para calcular a soma. Mas isso não é necessário, pois como vimos acima, dá para fazer tudo em um *loop* só.

É claro que nesse caso específico, como o número só pode estar entre zero e 20, não faz tanta diferença assim. Mas se for considerar números maiores, aí começa a fazer diferença.

Answer (score 0):

A partir do seu enunciado, entendi que você deseja implementar um programa que `solicita` um valor `inteiro`, `positivo` e `menor que 20` e, em seguida, deve devolver:

1. O `maior` valor entre `"1"` e `"n"`;
2. O `menor` valor entre `"1"` e `"n"`;
3. A `soma` de todos os valores entre `"1"` e `"n"`;
4. A `média aritmética` dos valores entre `"1"` e `"n"`;
5. A `quantidade` de números `"pares"` encontrados entre `"1"` e `"n"`;
6. A `quantidade` de números `"ímpares"` encontrados entre `"1"` e `"n"`.

A partir desse entendimento você pode implementar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input('Digite um número inteiro, positivo e menor que "20": '))
        if (n <= 0) or (n >= 20):
            print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas inteiros, positivos e menores que "20"!\033[m')
        else:
            break
    except:
        print('\033[31mValor INVÁLIDO! Digite apenas números inteiros!\033[m')

pares = impares = soma = 0
for c in range(1, n + 1):
    if c % 2 == 0:
        pares += 1
    else:
        impares += 1
    soma += c
mediaAritmetica = (soma / n)

print(f'\033[32mO maior valor é: {n}')
print(f'O menor valor é: 1')
print(f'A soma dos valores é: {soma}')
print(f'A média aritmética dos valores é: {mediaAritmetica:.2f}')
print(f'A quantidade de valores pares é: {pares}')
print(f'A quantidade de valores ímpares é: {impares}\033[m')
```

Observe o funcionamento do algoritmo no [repl.it](https://repl.it/join/wwyqmkbi-solkarped).

Observe que neste algoritmo, o primeiro `bloco` de códigos realiza a `captura` e `tratamento` do valor digitado. Este bloco restringe os valores digitados para `apenas` valores `inteiros`, `positivos` e `menores que 20`. Caso contrário, o programa exibirá um erro e solicitará novamente um valor coerente. Além disso, é bom notar que, o programa só irá avançar na execução se o usuário digitar um valor coerente.

**Observação:**

Neste código excluir a possibilidade de que o menor número seja "0".