# Faça um programa que inverta um número inteiro com dois algarismos

Tags: python, python-3.x

Você deve imprimir o número invertido seguido de um final de linha. Não é preciso imprimir o 0 mais a esquerda. Por exemplo, se o número digitado for 30, basta que você imprima 3 e não 03.

```
num=int(input())
if num > 0:
    a = num%10
    b = num//10%10
    d = str("%d%d"%(a, b))
    print(d)
else:
    num_ajus = num_ajus *10 + d
    print(num_ajus)
```

Eu quero quando eu digito o 40 aparece 4 não 04.

Comment: ignorando os erros, faça `print(int(d))`

Comment: @AugustoVasques Nesse caso específico, é bem mais simples fazer `a * 10 + b`, conforme [minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/445479/112052) abaixo :-)

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar.

Answer (score 1):

Seguindo o seu código, basta converter o conteúdo da variável `d` para inteiro utilizando a função `int`, essa conversão já removerá o zero a esquerda, para efetuar uma quebra de linha, podemos utilizar o `"\n"`:

```
num=int(input())

if num > 0:
    a = num%10
    b = num//10%10
    d = int(str("%d%d"%(a, b)))
    print(d, "\n")
else:
    num_ajus = num_ajus *10 + d
    print(num_ajus)
```

Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/WorstMellowNetworking

---

Veja um outro exemplo de como fazer isso, sendo que dessa forma, podemos trabalhar com muito mais que dois números.

Transformando número em lista, invertendo a ordem , utilizando join para converter a lista em string e então converto para inteiro (remove o zero):

```
#Solicito o número
num = input()

#Transformo o número digitado em uma lista
num = list(num)
#Faço a orndenação inversa da lista, aqui eu já teria um resultado bem próximo
num.reverse()
#Converto a lista para uma string e depois para inteiro, isso removerá o zero a esquerda
num = int("".join(num))

#Exibo o número e a quebra de linha
print(num, "\n")
```

Veja online: https://repl.it/repls/SunnyQuerulousDevices

Comment: Desculpa a pergunta sou novo nisso o que seria o .join

Comment: É um método da string, ele permite concatenar os dados presentes em uma lista por exemplo, separando os mesmo com o valor presente na string: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse exemplo aqui, tá bem simples: https://repl.it/repls/HumbleDistinctTitle

Comment: Obrigado Daniel, eu sou novo nesse mundo e estou tendo dificuldade em algumas provas da minha faculdade

Comment: Imagina, bons estudos! :)

Answer (score 1):

## Não precisa transformar os números em string

Você começou bem, usando matemática para obter os dígitos do número separadamente. Bastava continuar usando matemática para obter o resultado final:

```
# ATENÇÃO: o código só funciona para números com 2 algarismos (mais sobre isso no final da resposta)
num = int(input())

# assumindo que o número só tem 2 dígitos, não precisa fazer num // 10 % 10
dezena = num // 10
unidade = num % 10
print(unidade * 10 + dezena)
```

Pronto, só isso, fim.

Transformar os dígitos em string, só para depois transformar esta string em `int`, apesar de funcionar, é uma volta desnecessária (como é novo na área, já aprenda que "[funcionar é diferente de estar certo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgk8Q.png)").

<sup>*Você já tinha a faca e o queijo na mão (os dígitos), mas em vez de cortar (fazer uma conta simples), tentou acoplar a faca em uma moto-serra...*</sup>

Transformar em string só seria justificável se você precisasse formatar o  número (por exemplo, colocando zeros à esquerda ou algo do tipo), mas como você só precisava imprimir o valor numérico e nada mais, não precisa dar essa volta toda. Não complique o que pode ser resolvido de maneira simples.

---

O [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) já inclui uma quebra de linha no final, e não ficou claro se você quer adicionar **outra** quebra de linha. Se for esse o caso, faça:

```
print(unidade * 10 + dezena, "\n")
```

Se bem que o `print`, por *default*, inclui um espaço entre os parâmetros, então será impresso um espaço depois do número. Visualmente não fará diferença nesse caso, mas em programação qualquer caractere, inclusive aqueles que não "vemos", como espaços e TAB's, podem fazer diferença em muitos casos. Então você pode eliminar esse espaço mudando o separador:

```
print(unidade * 10 + dezena, '\n', sep='')
```

Mas como você está usando Python 3, há outras opções melhores, como o método [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) e [*f-string*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) (este último a partir da versão 3.6):

```
print('{}\n'.format(unidade * 10 + dezena))

# ou, em Python >= 3.6
print(f'{unidade * 10 + dezena}\n')
```

---

Outro detalhe importante é que o código acima só funciona para números com exatamente dois algarismos (que pelo título da pergunta, dá a entender que é um requisito).

Vi que você usou `num // 10 % 10` para obter o dígito correspondente à dezena, mas isso só é necessário se o número tiver 3 ou mais algarismos. Se tiver exatamente dois algarismos, usar `num // 10` é o suficiente.

De qualquer forma, o programa não valida se o número tem exatamente dois algarismos. Se só tiver um, o código acima (e também o primeiro código da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/445461/112052)) falha - se o número for 3, por exemplo, o resultado é 30, [veja](https://ideone.com/Ca8Qzp).

Nesse caso você poderia incluir uma verificação:

```
if 10 <= num <= 99:
    # usa o código acima
else:
    print('O número deve ter 2 algarismos')
```

Ou, se quiser aceitar qualquer quantidade de dígitos, inclusive números negativos (por exemplo, `-123` vira `-321`), então use um algoritmo mais geral - também usando somente a boa e velha matemática:

```
x = abs(num) # se o número for negativo, troca o sinal
inverso = 0
while x > 0:
    inverso = inverso * 10 + x % 10
    x //= 10
if num < 0: # se o número é negativo, troca o sinal
    inverso *= -1
print(f'{inverso}\n')
```

Se quiser se aprofundar nessa questão de inverter os dígitos e imprimi-los, há uma discussão um pouco mais detalhada [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/412148/112052).

---

A solução com lista da [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/445461/112052) seria interessante se você já recebesse uma lista com os dígitos. Mas criar a lista, inverter e juntar tudo pra só no final converter para número não é uma boa solução, pois se não for digitado um número, só vai dar erro no final, depois que você já faz todo o trabalho. Se o programa vai trabalhar com números, então continue fazendo a conversão no início (com `int(input())`) pois se não for digitado um número, já [dá erro logo no início](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) e você não tem todo o trabalho de inversão à toa.

Sem contar que, **se** a ideia é somente inverter a string que foi digitada, [nem precisava usar lista](https://ideone.com/Jk73ls).

Por fim, o ideal mesmo seria validar o que foi digitado e só prosseguir se for um número ([exemplo](https://ideone.com/4hIDTB)).