# Como limitar o numero de linhas escrevendo CSV Python?

Tags: python

Sou novo aqui, sou muito iniciante em programação e estou começando com Python. Estou em um projeto pessoal que esta bem adiantado mas estou com uma dificuldade bem especifica, quero escrever em um arquivo CSV somente um número desejado de linhas. Esse comando abaixo gera um arquivo gigante muitas vezes com mais de 30k linhas de dados mas por demonstração do sistema eu quero gravar somente 50 linhas de dados no arquivo;

```
with open("arquivo.csv","w",encoding='UTF-8') as f:#Enter your file name.
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
    writer.writerow(['username','user id','name','group'])
    for user in all_participants:
        if user.username:
            username= user.username
        else:
            username= ""
        if user.first_name:
            first_name= user.first_name
        else:
            first_name= ""
        if user.last_name:
            last_name= user.last_name
        else:
            last_name= ""
        name= (first_name + ' ' + last_name).strip()
        writer.writerow([username,user.id,name,target_group.title])
```

Como eu posso fazer para limitar a quantidade de informações gravadas:

Me disseram para usar a função *enumerator* mas estou apanhando, estou muito verde ainda kkk

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Recomendo a leitura da documentação disponível no link abaixo. Ela demonstra exemplos de contadores dentro de loop(s) e instruções de controle de fluxo de execução dentro de um loop com a instrução `for`. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/322/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-break-pass-e-continue-em-python

Answer (score 1):

A função `enumerate` é aplicada no iterador que vai na últma parte de um comando `for` - e o que ela faz é, para cada item, retornar não só o item, mas a sua posição na iteração - então ele funciona como um contador.

Aí, é só usar um `if` no código, e quando o elemento estiver além do número desejado, usar o comando `break` para sair do `for`:

```py
limit = 50

with open("arquivo.csv","w",encoding='UTF-8') as f:#Enter your file name.
    writer = csv.writer(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
    writer.writerow(['username','user id','name','group'])
    for counter, user in enumerate(all_participants):
        if limit and counter > limit:
            break
        if user.username:
            username= user.username
        else:
            username= ""
        if user.first_name:
            first_name= user.first_name
        else:
            first_name= ""
        if user.last_name:
            last_name= user.last_name
        else:
            last_name= ""
        name= (first_name + ' ' + last_name).strip()
        writer.writerow([username,user.id,name,target_group.title])
```

Aqui, em vez de colocar o "50" direto dentro de um código, coloquei numa variável: isso permite que o mesmo código seja usado numa função, que pode receber esse limite como parâmetro. Do jeito que coloquei o teste `if limit and counter > limit:` se a variável limit for `None` ou `0`, o teste sempre falha, e o limite é ignorado.

O `enumerate` funciona como descrevi acima. Ele retorna uma tupla de 2 elementos - o (contador, item_original) - e a sintaxe de variáveis separadas por vírgula na primeira parte do `for` funciona certinho com isso, distribuindo os valores para as variáveis respectivas (`for counter, user ...`);

Por fim, é legal ter em mente que se o enumerate não existisse, ou você não soubesse de sua existência, o problema seria resolvido com um contador mantido manualmente:

```
...
writer.writerow(...)
counter = 0
for user in all_participants:
     counter += 1
     if counter > limit:
         break
     ...
```